# Generic solution to Eclipse CDT's symbol 'X' could not be resolved?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse-cdt

I have a project with C++ and C files. The code compiles and runs correctly, but I need to get rid of the following error:

> Symbol 'ERANGE' could not be resolved

I was able to reproduce it with these two files (latest x64 Elipse Juno on Ubuntu):

main.h:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H_
#define MAIN_H_

extern "C" {
#include <errno.h>
}

#endif /* MAIN_H_ */
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cassert>
#include "main.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    assert(errno != ERANGE); // <-- CDT ERROR here
    return 0; }
```

Doing *Open Declaration* on ERANGE correctly takes me to /usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h file.

The following workarounds to similar issues DID NOT work:

- Setting *Indexer -> Use active build configuration*
- Manually adding the ERANGE symbol to project *Paths and Symbols*
- Adding main.cpp to *Preferences -> C/C++ -> Code Analysis -> Symbol is not resolved -> Customize Selected... -> Scope -> Exclusion patterns*

The only solution that will work is disabling the *Symbol is not resolved* error completely, but that will cause me to miss real issues.

**Edit:**
CDT bug filed https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404017

Comment: I don't know if this will help you but I find that the CDT indexer does not always update itself correctly or reliably. When things get out of sync, right click the project and select Index | Freshen All Files. That usually resolves these types of issues for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the Eclipse CDT code analysis tool ([codan](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/designs/StaticAnalysis)). I recommend submitting a bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/?product=CDT).